# python jedi auto-complete print() problem

Tags: python, printing, autocomplete, flush, jedi

I just installed jedi auto-completion from sublimetext 3 in python because I wanted to make code write easier.

after everythings done.. when i write string. and all the statements and class names pops up. great

but problem comes here:

after i type `print` and type`(`

automatically  `print(sep=..., end=..., file=..., flush=...)` pops  up..

i don't want this big line.. i just want to print `"()"`

what should i do?

i use ubuntu 18, python version 3.7.2

Comment: Could you provide your code/example, please?

Comment: please, check out my next question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510148/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests-even-after-installing-requests-f

Answer (score 1):

Go to the sublime text editor.
preference > browse packages
And then click on it and it will take you to the file manager (Where the packages are save for sublime).
Now there find **JD - Python Autocompletion**
then head to **JD-Python Autocompletion > sublime_jd > utils.py**
Now you have to edit this file...
In this file around line number 34, you will find a line mentioned below (Use find to find this line)

```
complete_funcargs = get_settings_param(
    view, 'auto_complete_function_params', 'all')
```

Now just remove **all**. Like below:-

```
complete_funcargs = get_settings_param(
    view, 'auto_complete_function_params', '')
```

That's all, Now restart the sublime and enjoy